# What if I don't want to become one with my supposed creator?

Tags: death, life, souls

This question entertains the hypothesis that we are the product of one intelligence/consciousness and that our life purpose is to refine our souls to the degree that are once again one with this source. The expected answer is hypothetical and therefore within the parameters of the provided hypothesis.

On numerous occasions, I've read that our spiritual apex is for our souls to be refined, through incarnations and experiences thereof, to the point that we become one with the supposed creator of all souls. This is also described as "returning to the source" in New Age esotericism. The book "Conversations with God" also outlines this precept in detail and I'm pretty sure Hermetic Alchemy touches on this.

To me, this is the ultimate form of death, not a mere mortal death but an esoteric death. What if I wish to retain my individuality? What if I don't want to be assimilated? I want to be more than a mere experiential conduit for my creator.

Comment: First, please demonstrate the existence of a creator who cares what you want....

Comment: @NelsonAlexander I can't nor am I postulating that such a creator exists. It's a [hypothesis](https://www.google.ie/search?q=define+hypothesis). I was hoping the word "supposed" in my question would infer this. Nonetheless, I've added a preceding paragraph to my question for clarification.

Comment: @ClarusDignus who says that you'd lose your consciousness?  You might be part of a greater whole, but you would still retain your consciousness. The best way to understand this is to try to experience unity through deep meditation.  If you're able to reach that state, you'll get a taste of what these faiths promise.

Comment: @ClarusDignus, I am not sure what sort of criterion you are using when you "compare" different categories of "death." Or what you mean by "esoteric" death. And the phrase "What if I want..." is not conducive to reasoned answers. But if you are "nihilphobic," to coin a term, you are better off with a "divine creator" than with science, where your fate within the laws of entropy has a more thoroughly annihilating "oneness" than most concepts of any afterlife. In heaven there is presumably some conservation law pertaining to "you." Frankly, I think there are better ways to spend our "worries."

Comment: @NelsonAlexander I'm not sure of what comparison criterion might exist considering I'm addressing this as an isolated hypothesis. Esoteric death = death of that which exists beyond our mortal flesh (soul, intelligence etc.).Why is "what if I want" not conducive to reason? Does "nihilphobic" suggest that I'm fearful of the potential meaningless of life? What better thing is there to spend our "worries" on than immortality? Transhumanism or the cultivation of the soul/consciousness are our only two tickets. I'll hedge my bets. I don't want to end.

Comment: I'm not religious. I learned almost nothing. I developed my own abstract thinking independently which might turn out to be similar to abstract thinking of religious people taught by religion if they're doing it. Anything is possible. It is possible that we are figments of a brain that can store a lot more information. It's very very hard for that being to have full control of their thoughts. So it created animals that were free of depression and pulled off advanced tasks very passionately without a scramble. Maybe that being also created us with a glitch of not knowing how to see things

Comment: another way by living in the moment and seeing everything through the thinking you're doing right then. That being of course is thinking an analysing your brain so even after you're dead in the part of his brain that is an emulation of our universe, that being will still have actions that are like a continuation of your brain under the influence of alcohol or in a slightly sleepy state. I'm not scared of having a bit of alcohol in my system. I still define my future self with that in my system as a future of me. If you define that not to be a future of you, you will be really unhappy now

Comment: because you are defining a future in such a way that that is not your future. Eventually when it continues on, you would feel like what you are experiencing now really was your past. The brain would very much be like a continuation of what it was before. I guess you would decide to finally let your past problems go and wait until the problem happens that you die in this universe and don't want to because you don't know what it's like on the other side. In general, it is a good idea to wait until a problem you can't prevent happens and then take useful action based on it instead of purposely

Comment: and unnecessarily creating problems that don't need to be there. Once the problem happens that you get taken to the other side, you might as well let go of your past problems now that you learned that you aren't dead on the other side and cannot die. Maybe you would decide you might as well let go of them and be like "It's okay. They've over now." But you might be thinking it's kind of too bad you didn't do it earlier because your problems would have gone away earlier and the sooner, the better, and you had real big problems at the time because you defined what you're experiencing now not to

Comment: be your future and therefore defined things in such a way that you were going to be dead for ever according to your definition at the time and were scared and it's kind of too bad, you weren't lucky enough to have the true natural state of mind at the time that just thought of it another way and defined it to be your future. I see and notice that religions that have a lesson for which there is a complicated explanation according to science for why that lesson ends up so useful and working so well tend to spread.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Short Answer**: These philosophies claim we all want this, we just don't know it.

**Long Answer**:

Religions and philosophies that espouse this say that this is the greatest bliss of all and those who say they don't want unity only say that because they don't realize what unity is like; if they did, they'd want it.  In fact, part of the path of purification is realizing that what we normally pursue for our fulfillment is but a shallow imitation of this true fulfillment.

This argument is similar to those of some ancient Greek philosophers, who claimed that people did not seek the good because of ignorance and if they recognized the true good, they would seek it.

Becoming one with God doesn't mean losing your consciousness.  You can maintain consciousness without a sense of self or individuality, although it's a hard state to imagine.  You can experience a reduced version of this state if you practice meditation or contemplation.  It may take you some time, and you may not consistently achieve this, but if you do, you'll get a taste of what this unity is like (but far more blissful because more complete).

Spinoza's philosophy also included unity with God (defined as all that is), but his seemed to preclude the survival of one's consciousness.  As such, some have criticized it, claiming that this "immortality" was nothing like how most people defined immortality, and thus was nothing more than equivocation (much like his definition of "God").

Comment: @JoWehler I don't know what the OP wants.  I'm explaining what those philosophies claim.  They claim that this is what we all want, but this is not my claim. I'll edit the answer to make it clearer

Comment: Thank you for intuiting what I was asking and for introducing me to Spinoza. His viewpoints sound similar to animism. Unity isn't as undesirable to me as merging irrevocably. It's abstract for me to conceive the merging of the consciousness of two minds let alone every mind that ever has/will existed.

Answer (score 1):

What happens if I wish not to grow older, or if wish to have the power of flight at the mere expression of my will, so that I can fly above mountains or indeed above clouds?

Tough I would say to myself; the world is not constituted like that as I might have imagined it when I was a child or when I watch a movie whose power of suggestion is such that I can forget how the world is and suppose it to be as malleable as a moment in the minds eye; or like the rose of a rose-petal rolled between finger and thumb.

But if not like such a petal, then perhaps like a flower, like a bloom: constituted as Spinoza described it, where nature as we see it is an aspect of God - or also as in his description neccessary being; one modality being extension - things, another modality being thought.

In this emanationist cosmology a man has his individual consciousness, has the power of will and intention; yet is at the same time *already* also a part of a whole.

But perhaps this man is a pure materialist, claiming all things are purely matter and force that there is nothing else; and death is a pure death being a dissolution into the mere matter from which he was originally constituted from; and he claims this because he is, and he emphasises this, an empiricist - he observes and takes note.

As an empiricist he notes the existence of people who, oddly enough, do not go along with this thesis, who insist on something else and they too offer proofs and demonstrations and others do not: claiming without demonstrating and others demonstrate without the actual wit or pith of demonstration; and others wish not, wishing silence or solitude.

And he notes with a degree of desperation and a note of melancholy that people are various, and do not conform to his will and vision, even when laid out with great rhetorical skill and panache: some will miss the obvious, and others will not; some will go to great lengths, and others do not; some shall will the all, and others being contraries will turn and twist with times tempo...

And then his mind drifts off to a piece of music he was listening to yesterday evening, Coplands *Fanfare for the Common Man*, where each note individual unto itself and powerfully so was yet also in harmony with the one preceding it, and the one succeeding it; and sounding it seemed, or so he thought, into the void, yet being buoyed up by the whole as he felt himself bouyed up listening to the whole awashed, and washed up in the static of his times ...

Forests of mourning pine - and the morning sound sounding bright in the dusk folded into his night; all quiet too, as the Don flows when the sky murdered falls flapping.

O Cloudwalker, walking on clouds:
Daedalus his hands laughing like a tyrant amongst the shapes that move towards the snake

*Pitchblack pony, Luna grande (+)
A sack of olives at my saddle
Though I know the roads I travel
I shall never get to Cordoba*

(+) From Lorcas *Cancion del Jinete*

Comment: First two paragraphs: I'm not content accepting limitation especially so when told "It's just the way things are.". Was it not but a few decades ago that physiologists believed the human body would explode if it ran under a five minute mile? Your commentary on Spinoza: If Spinoza was so convinced that we end as and with our flesh, why then did he not commit his life to seeking biological immortality rather than self-indulgently and redundantly musing about it? Why was he so accepting of his end? It's illogical for a life form to want to end (with the exception of a merciful death).

Comment: Glad to hear it; let us and the world know when you've developed an anti-gravity device ...

Comment: [Never say never](https://www.newscientist.com/article/dn13556-10-impossibilities-conquered-by-science/) though I'm rather content not spontaneously meandering into orbit. :-) Jokes aside, what other imperative is there other than immortality? It can only be achieved biologically (nanotechnology, transhumanism et al.) or esoterically. Any other commitment, concern, priority, focus or action is as redundant as it is irrational. Our misguided acceptance is a form of mass social insanity. Thank you for your clearly educated and beautifully written answer no less.